# Create new output folder on each run

Tags: youtube-dl

I'm currently using youtube-dl on Windows with a config file that contains this:

`-o 'B:/Users/Hashim/Desktop/New Folder/%(title)s.%(ext)s'`

...which saves the output files to a folder called New Folder on my Desktop. The problem with this is that if there already exists a folder called New Folder, it'll just place the music in the existing folder, whereas I'm wanting the program to create a new folder for each batch of downloads that I do, regardless of what the folder's called.

Is there any way to get the program to create a new output folder for each batch of downloads it does?

Comment: Why don't you use the title of the song as the name of the folder?

Comment: Because I'm downloading several videos at a time, all from the same playlist.

Comment: I've created a similar application, but it is for linux, if you want to check that out, might give you some ideas: https://github.com/ArielAleksandrus/PlaylistDownloader

Answer (score 1):

I've created a BATCH script for you.

The solution I came up with is: As you want to have a different folder for each set of songs, and you don't care about the name (You were using "New Folder"), you'll probably like the idea of having folders "New Folder0" "New Folder1" "New Folder2", so to accomplish that, here is the BATCH script.

```
SET /A var=0
:loop
IF EXIST "%cd%\New Folder%var%" (
  SET /A var=var+1
  GOTO loop
)
MKDIR "New Folder%var%"
```

So, the BATCH script checks what is the last "New Folder" you have. If it is "New Folder4", it will create "New Folder5" for you. But you should make sure you are in the directory you want to create the folder. You could replace %cd% with the path you prefer (under Music/ or Video/) for example

Comment: That's perfect, behaves exactly as I want, thanks for that. I'm not understanding how I'd get it to work with youtube-dl though, what sort of setting up do I need to connect the two?

Comment: Ok, so your folder is "New Folder%var". Now, you should only append the youtube-dl command  to the BATCH script, like: youtube-dl -o "New Folder%var%/%(title)s.%(ext)s"

Comment: Make sure, however, to put the full path when you create the folder and when you pass it to youtube-dl. This way you will avoid problems. Also, please upvote and mark the answer as accepted if you liked it and solved your problem.

Comment: So youtube-dl would need to be run in a batch script for this to work? I was hoping I could get it to work whilst retaining the ability to use youtube-dl as I normally do, in cmd. Something that extends the program and adds the feature permanently rather than needs to be run everytime.

Comment: running on the script and running on command line is the same thing

Comment: I understand that, but I would need to run the script in the command line every time I ran the program, right? Rather than just set and forget?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101235/discussion-between-aleksandrus-and-hashim).

Comment: For anyone else's reference, upvoted because this is currently the closest answer, but doesn't do exactly what I'd wanted, as it would require the running of the script every time I used the program rather than the set-and-forget solution I'd wanted.